# .map doesn't appear to be acting on individual items

Tags: swift

I'm performing a CloudKit query that retrieves an array of CKRecord. I then want to extract just the title from all the return items. To do this I thought I'd use a `map` function, but I'm getting an error on the individual items in the map that `Value of type '[CKRecord]' has no member 'value'`

So for some reason it thinks that the individual items in the map are the actual array of records itself. Can anyone see what's wrong here? I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious.

So records should be an array of CKRecord

```
 var tags:[String] = []
 CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: { (records, error) in

            let titles = records.map {  $0.value(forKey:"title")}
            tags.append(titles)
        })
```

Value of type '[CKRecord]' has no member 'value'

It doesn't matter if I explicitly name $0 to another variable such as `record` (in case it was referencing the wrong argument number from the initial closure) I get the same error.

In fact if I use a standard forEach loop this works without an issue

```
  records?.forEach({ (record) in
                tags.append(record.value(forKey: "title") as! String)
            })
```

Comment: `records` is optional, you have to unwrap it before you map.

Comment: I thought it would be something simple, just a shame the error message was nothing to do with being optional or unwrapping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dan hints at the problem, but it's worth exploring.

```
 let titles = records.map { $0.value(forKey:"title")}
```

This line isn't doing what you think. `records` is Optional, so this is calling `Optional.map` which means "apply this if there is a value, and do not apply if there is no value." The value is an array, so `$0` is the array, not the values in the array.

This form of `map` is absolutely natural and obvious to people with a Haskell background, and mysterious to just about everyone else. You can think of it as "an Optional is like a collection of 0 or 1 element" and then it probably makes more sense. (More formally, both Arrays and Optionals are Functors, which are things that obey specific rules when `map` is applied to them.)

The solution is to use `?.` to unwrap the optional before applying the map:

```
let titles = records?.map { $0.value(forKey:"title")}
```